# I don't understand what this question mean, but I need to prove it for homework

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization, symmetric-matrices

Let A be a real symmetric matriz that σ(A) = {0}. Prove that A=O

This exercise is for orthogonal diagonalization. How do I apply the spectrum theorem to get this proof?

Comment: The question is asking you to prove that if a symmetric matrix has all eigenvalues equal to zero, then the matrix itself is zero. Note, that for non-symmetric matrices, this is not true. For example, the matrix $$\left( \begin{matrix}0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{matrix} \right)$$ has all of its eigenvalues equal to zero but is not the zero matrix.

Comment: Yes, $\sigma(A)$ here is likely the *spectrum*, or set of eigenvalues.  ($s= \sigma$ for $\sigma$pectrum).

Comment: Thanks, how can I write this in general?

Answer (score 2):

**Hints:**

=== A matrix has zero as its *unique* eigenvalue (in any extension of the base field)  iff it is nilpotent

=== A *symmetric matrix* is always diagonalizable (over the reals)

=== The only nilpotent diagonalizable matrix is the zero one.